# moving div horizontally?

Tags: javascript, html

sliding div using javascript

i have three div with some content. i need the div to be moved one after another . moving div horizontally

any idea..

Comment: Put more question marks in the title!!!!!

Comment: You should consider using jQuery instead of coding this in plain javascript. Especially if you want the divs to move to the new place instead of "jumping" over there instantly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery and the `slideDown()` and `slideUp()` functions. See http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/sliding/

Answer (score 3):

You shall have to set position=absolute and then set x and y for the div. You can change their x and y inside a javascript. There are plenty of available scripts for sliding.

Answer (score 1):

Could be done like this:

```
// Moving the element to the 200 x 200 coordinate relative to
// the parent element, WITHOUT JQUERY

var elementStyles = document.getElementById("someDiv").style;
elementStyles.position = "absolute";
elementStyles.top = 200 + "px";
elementStyles.left = 200 + "px";

// Moving the element to the 200 x 200 coordinate relative to
// the parent element, WITH JQUERY

$("#someDiv").animate({
    top: 200 + "px",
    left: 200 + "px"
});

// If the position should be changed relative to the current position,
// add a `"+=" +` in front of `200` in the jQuery script, like this:

left: "+=" + 200 + "px"
```